# What is the maximum 64 bit integer (number) value?

Tags: programming, microprocessor

I already know that the maximum integers for ranges higher than 24-bit (16 777 216) will very likely exceed 1 000 000 000, so, what is the maximum **64 bit** integer? It is larger than 10 bilion?

Comment: This is more of a math.stackexchange.com question, surely?

Comment: This is in no way related to retro computing. If at all it's about computing in general or more fitting math, as it's about numeric systems.

Comment: Have you heard of Google? Type "maximum 64 bit integer" into google and it's the first answer returned,  you don't even have to click through yo a page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ten billion can be represented in 34 bits, never mind 64.  The hexadecimal representation (in which each digit contains four bits) is `0x2540BE400`.

The maximum (unsigned) 64-bit integer is `18446744073709551615`.  This is (2^64)-1, which is essentially the square of (2^32)-1, which is "about" 4 billion.

In general, you can estimate that every 10 bits represents 3 decimal digits.  For 64 bits, that means a good estimate would be 16 (from the 4 leftover bits) followed by 18 zeroes (6*3).  As you can see, this gets reasonably close to the true value.

Comment: Downvote because: should not have been answered - obviously shows signs of NO research having been done by OP since in this case "research" would have been the obvious google query which would have answered the low-quality question.

Comment: Fun fact @davidbak, this question is what you get when you google it.

Comment: @BrandonDyer - Stack Exchange is a Google attractor.